# Angular2: how to run on production

Tags: angular

Currently I'm passed Angular2 QuickStart guide, where I was working with angular and was really impressed with it. I was running my code by
`npm start`
and reviewing changes on `localhost:3000`
But now I want to implement it with my empty laravel 5.1 project (it is not so necessary right now)
So, how can I make angular work without npm start? Or I should do it always on production server??? How can I add a nice route, without 3000 port?
I was thinking to compile code with gulp, but someone said that `http` module not working without server, is it right?

Comment: What does 'http module not working without server' refer to? You already have a web server with PHP and Laravel, don't you?

Comment: That is the trick! Currently I'm completely stuck right on this moment, because I can't find solution for running Angular2 application without npm start or Angular CLI support.

Comment: The question isn't related to Angular. It is about configuring web server for SPA. It should return index file for every GET request except for existing static files. If you don't want to mess with web server configuration, then stick to `npm start`, it is there exactly to ease the life of frontend devs. You can ask a new question that applies to your web server, but there are existing answer on SO for all popular web servers, so it will certainly be a dupe.

Comment: I think that you didn't get what I'm talking about or I was not clear enough, and I'm sorry if so, but the main problem right now is that I want to get Angular2 work without 3000 port and` npm start` command like Angular 1.5 was doing before, I suppose it would be a good way to compile `.ts into .js` or something when coding thing is done, I think it's relevant question

Comment: Compilation is a separate task. If you're referring to https://github.com/angular/quickstart project, it is `npm run tsc`.

Comment: I made the same questions a few weeks ago. Check this out https://github.com/bertolo1988/saco